# array json from APO POST to html ionic 6?

Tags: arrays, json, api, ionic-framework, post

I have an API that sends a Json to me. But I don't know how to show it into my html. I know that I have to use Ngfor but it doesn't work. This is my code.

```
 SaveData(){
    var dataToSend2 = "Hola";
    var dataToSend = {"num_personal":"419","anio_pago":"2022","periodo_pago":"09"};
    console.log(dataToSend);
    this.proveedor.saveData(dataToSend).subscribe(
      (dataReturnFromService)=>{
        this.dataFromService = (dataReturnFromService);
        let obj = JSON.parse(this.dataFromService);
        this.dataFromJson = obj;      

        console.log(obj);
      }
    )
  }
```

This part gives me a Json with the data from my API, but I don't know how to use the Json "obj" to show it into the html

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to show your html code. but it should work if it looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of dataFromJson">
    <span>{{x.label}}</td>
</div>
```